How can I convert user query to sql for a search engine to get exact matching documents from db, the query is in japanese
I am using tfidf as a search algorithm but tfidf doesn't give exact matches so could you suggest a different algo  that can match exactly with the database .With tfidf when we search for show me domestic stocks domestic bonds also come up in the search and I want only domestic stocks in answers.
We have tried tfidf also llm for our use case but llm also gets confused and gives extra filters in answers
